# Sub-enumeration with the same font size in beamer

Tags: beamer, lists, fontsize, enumerate

I have a `beamer` slide with a several recursive sub-enumerations, e.g.:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Do A
  \begin{enumerate}
     \item Have B
     \item Load C
     \item Backup D
     \begin{enumerate}
       \item Connect to E
       \item Transfer F
     \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
  \item \ldots
\end{enumerate}
```

`beamer`'s default rendering is to make the font smaller for each extra level of indentation.  How can I keep all the fonts with the same size, also, preferably, large size?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

reset the fontsize:

```
\setbeamerfont*{itemize/enumerate body}{size=\large}
\setbeamerfont*{itemize/enumerate subbody}{parent=itemize/enumerate body}
\setbeamerfont*{itemize/enumerate subsubbody}{parent=itemize/enumerate body}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.  It also catches the numbers.

Comment: @herbert The fonts are fine, but the items are too congested. Any idea how to automatically increase `\itemsep`?

Answer (score 7):

You could adjust the corresponding templates, such as

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{\large}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subbody begin}{\large}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subsubbody begin}{\large}
```

for the text, and if required also for the numbers, for example

```
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{\large\insertenumlabel.}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}{\large\insertenumlabel.\insertsubenumlabel}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subsubitem}{%
  \large\insertenumlabel.\insertsubenumlabel.\insertsubsubenumlabel}
```

Comment: It would appear that the first group of `\setbeamertemplate` commands sets the font size for both the enumerate items' bodies as well as their lnumbers (even though the `beamer` manual's explanation doesn't seem to indicate this to be the case).