# Smaller font sizes in second level of itemize/enumerate in beamer

Tags: beamer, lists, fontsize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sub-enumeration with the same font size in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40877/sub-enumeration-with-the-same-font-size-in-beamer)

In the second level of enumeration or items in [beamer](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/), the fonts are automatically made smaller in size. Please see this minimal example,

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{times}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{Test Frame}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item This is in normal size
  \item So is this
    \begin{itemize}
    \item But this one is smaller
    \item Also this one is smaller
    \end{itemize}
  \item We can use the \verb+\normalsize+ command to make regular size
    \begin{itemize}
      \normalsize
    \item This comes out in regular size.
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However, I do not want the second level fonts to be smaller. As you can see above, the `\normalsize` command can be used to get this. I find this manual approach too cumbersome and looking for something *automatic*.

I tried hacking the beamer code, but got lost in the labyrinth. Looks like I need to customize `\usebeamerfont` or some such, but can not proceed further.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Found the answer here, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40877/sub-enumeration-with-the-same-font-size-in-beamer?rq=1. Sorry for asking here.